# Is using Python f-strings effective for generating Python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, code-generation

I have not found any related questions or examples of Python code using f-strings to generate Python code. Is there an underlying problem that I should know about? f-strings are really convenient and seem to be rather efficient for my needs.

I am generating some python scripts that can be used in the command line for automatically processing folders with remote sensing images. I was going to manually write some files by hand but realized is was relatively easy to automate the process by externalizing metadata regarding the expressions.

Program logic:

- Extract expressions containing information on the different types of calculations that could be performed on the images (any sort of remote sensing indice)
- Iterate through expressions
- Create file with expression name (and other standards)
- Insert expression information into f-strings
- Write f-string to create file

I will also generate some tests automatically once settled on the method to be used. Is there a limit from which f-strings will not handle the code efficiently?

Some people have discussed using Python templates like Jinja2. However, if f-strings are sufficient I do not wish to integrate another external dependency.

```py
from expressions_meta import expressions

for key in expressions.keys():
    file_name = '_'.join([key, 'dir', 'cl.py'])

    with open(file_name, 'w') as f:

        f.write(f"""
import sys
import getopt

from gdal_dir_calc import GDALDirCalc

expression = {expressions[key]}

band_meta = {{}}

[...]

gdal_dir_obj.main()
""")
```

I might just be overly cautious but I think the topic could address other applications as well.

Any other tips regarding the use of f-strings for Python code generation or another tool?

Comment: Why do you even need many scripts with (potentially) almost exactly the same source code, rather than a single script that accepts input from CLI arguments or conf files?

Comment: Irrelevant to the question, but you do realize that `file_name` will actually be overwritten on each of the `expressions` iterations, right? You'll end up with just the last value.

Comment: @DeepSpace: The objective is to have specific indice calculators that can be easily used by people with little technical background. Like calculating an NDVI or NDSI and having only to pass the required and simplified arguments for the calculation.

Comment: @MatiasCicero: Yes, the program generates as many scripts as there are expressions.

Comment: @DeepSpace: To answer your questions more clearly, the script is based on https://www.gdal.org/gdal_calc.html. gdal_calc already provides a way to treat individual images in a general command line utility. The interest of my project is processing directories of images and having a more abstracted command line interface (having more explicit arguments than (A-B)/(A+B) for example).

Comment: Except for proof of concepts or demo, I have seldom seen acceptable use cases for script generation. It is often both simple to write and to maintain to have one single script and an associated config file, or options. Next, on Linux of other Unix-like systems, a single command can be linked to multiple names and the command name can be used to select some default options. So my advice is: is it possible? of course yes ; should you do that? probably not.

Comment: @SergeBallesta: Thanks for your answer. I already have a general command linking to multiple names. I am looking into to the design. Any recommandations on documentation regarding config files or more generally on CLI architecture?

Comment: @ZacharyDeziel: hard to say... The standard library already contains the `configparser` and `json` modules that can be used for human readable (and writable) config files, and `argparse` for parsing options. That should be an acceptable entry point. For CLI tools depending on your needs, `cmd` and or `shlex` can be useful, as could be the `readline` module if you want to offer autocompletion. It really depend on your requirements...

Comment: @SergeBallesta: Thank you. If you change your comments to an answer I would accept it. More a question of design than using f-strings to generate scripts (as usual).

Comment: @ZacharyDeziel: Feel free to use my comments to build an answer and accept it. I am too lazy to do it myself :-). After this comment, it is perfectly fine for the SO rules and code of conduct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### If you are coming across this question, be sure to review the design of your program.

Most likely you are trying to implement a solution in which you violate DRY principles.

### For command line applications:

Instead of generating many specific commands, look into to passing a name argument which in turn can be used with a selection of arguments.

From the standard library, some tools that may be helpful are `configparser`, `shlex`, `cmd`, `getopt` and `argparse`. See the standard library documentation on these tools.

[Click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/) is an interesting third party package.

Thanks @SergeBallesta for your helpful comments.